# Charts.JS - Too Many Charts? - Loading Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, charts, chart.js

I have **60+ charts loading on page** on a dashboard. On desktop it is working but on mobile occasionally on reload *all of the charts* will disappear and have to be reloaded to be visible.

If I remove most of the charts this issue seems to go away.

Is there a correct way to load 60+ charts using charts.js?

Any advice?

Here is an example of my set up:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
labels: ["Seeker", "Rock", "Examiner", "Uniter", "Counselor"],
datasets: [
{
label: "",
backgroundColor: ["#ff4757", "#8e44ad","#3c40c6","#2ed573","#f9ca24"],
data: [seekerNum, rockNum, examinerNum, uniterNum, counselorNum]
}
]
},
options: {
maintainAspectRatio: false,
beginAtZero: true,
title: {
display: true,
text: 'Your Personality Score'
}
}
});
```

Front end:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
<p class='largeBodyText'> Chart #1: </p>

<canvas id="doughnut-chart" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to split the 60+ charts among 3 pages. I'd love to know the reason for the error but splitting them up completely solved the loading issue. If anyone knows the maximum charts on one page recommended by charts.js feel free to share!